Browser Compatibility Issue Encountered with Razorpay
I have integrate Razorpay in my Angular application version 17 and when user click on payNow browser returns

The browser is not supported
Please try payment in another browsers

I have tried making the changes in code but didn't work, I think my code is correct but don't know where the issue is
